# How to add border to button?

Tags: android, eclipse

I would to know how to have a border to separate my buttons
in my xml file.
Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LinearLayout with no children and a height of 1 DP (assuming you are separating them vertically)

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/white"/> <!-- Or #FFFFFF -->

<Button android:id="@+id/button2" />
```

You can play with other options but this should give you a basic idea of what (I think) you're looking for. Try elaborating and showing some sample code for future question so we can understand your problem and help more!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_marginRight= "2dp" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button2"
 android:layout_marginRight= "2dp" />
```

This sets a padding of 2dp on the right side of the button inside a linearlayout.

This is preferable to calling another transparent view or a transparent linearlayout because you save yourself from creating unnecessary views by using the built in layout tools of your linearlayout.